# Cant import jpg file with react and phoenix

Tags: reactjs, webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework, webpack-2

im trying to use some images in my react code

```
import stepper1 from '../assets/static/HomePage/stepper1.png'
```

but i get this error at server run:

```
ERROR in ./js/components/assets/static/HomePage/card11.jpg
Module parse failed: Unexpected character 'ي┐╜' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./js/components/_components/HomeCards.js 29:0-60 83:15-23
 @ ./js/components/HomePage/HomePage.js
 @ ./js/components/HomePage/index.js
 @ ./js/app.js
 @ multi ./js/app.js
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please paste your code which produces the error - it's impossible to provide any assistance without it.

Comment: This sounds more like a webpack issue than a react, elixir or Phoenix issue.

Comment: @JustinWood actually it is . problem was size of image, i use < file-loader > for that and now its work!

Answer (score 1):

it is because of web-pack need file-louder to handle image with size by using [this link](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/file-loader-for-large-size-images-97b90249aef) it work's.